# Get excerpt around search word

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx

I'm using Sphinx to index and search my website.

Is there a way to return excerpt (searched word and few words around it), when searching for some word.

Right now I'm using this package [scalia](https://github.com/scalia/sphinxsearch).

```
 $results = SphinxSearch::search($search, $index_type);

 // I Set match, sort and ranking mode
 $results
    ->setMatchMode($search_mode)
    ->setSortMode($sort_mode, $sort_column)
    ->setRankingMode(\Sphinx\SphinxClient::SPH_RANK_SPH04);
  //set field weights
  $results->setFieldWeights(array('title'  => 10,'content'=> 5));

  //and get results
  $results = $results->limit(300, 0, 1000, 100000)->query();
```

Is there a way to manage Sphinx to return excerpt of text where it found searched keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `BuildExcerpts` function from the SphinxAPI
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-buildexcerpts

Alas that extension, does not seem to expose the function, so would have to either modify the extension, or just bypass it.

Comment: Yes, it seems that's it. Thanks, I'll try.